# Can dupehammers retag AND hammer now, or is this merely a bug?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, dupehammer

My experience has been that a dupehammer doesn't work if you added the tag you have a hammer in yourself. Today we had a Q in SOCVR that had been edited into shape and thus reopened. I asked the OP what language he wanted answers in (was only tagged [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)) and he responded PHP. I [tagged the question thus](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57654490/revisions) and then found a duplicate that covered it.

To my surprise [it closed and listed me as the hammer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57654490/2370483). Is this a bug or some unmentioned feature change?

Comment: Per ["The Meta"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268278/it-looks-like-the-duplicate-banner-changed-how-does-it-work-now) this is not the intended behavior.

Comment: php, javascript and jquery was removed in revision 6 of the question

Comment: Does it really make sense to close this as "can no longer be reproduced"? I'm pretty sure other people could still encounter the same scenario.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No bug here as far as I can tell.

The question was originally tagged with [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag, so you didn't really add the tag.

Comment: Ah, so it was. Good catch

Comment: For context, it was removed by OP in revision 6.

Comment: @Zoe true, but is it relevant? I mean, if it would have been removed by a different user, the OP here wouldn't be able to hammer the question? Anyway, this answer isn't full anyway, see Sonic answer for the real picture. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Per [this Meta Stack Exchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269103/cant-single-handedly-reopen-a-dupehammered-q-after-editing-gold-tag-to-another/310784#310784):

> The rules are:
>
> 1. There has to be a tag on the post currently in which you have a gold badge
> 2. You can't have been the first person to add that tag to the post (or have participated in adding it the first time)

Since the tag was present in the current revision at the time you closed, and you weren't the first person to add in the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag (the author added it in the initial revision), the system let you hammer it.